# ASP.NET MVC best way for searching anagrams in a database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, ef-code-first

I'm working on a mini project and trying to make a program that when you input a word, it will find anagrams from a big db of around 70000 words, it needs also to have the same number of characters e.g.(dogs = gods and not god or dog).

So far I managed to make a search, when I search I will find all the words that contain a part of the word I write

```
public ActionResult CheckAnagram(string word)
{
        IQueryable<Anagram> wordDictionary = db.Anagrams;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
        {
            wordDictionary = wordDictionary.Where(a => a.Name.Contains(word));
        }

        return View(wordDictionary.ToList());
}
```

I'm not sure what would be the best idea to do this, it's a pretty big db and what i can imagine is that I have to go multiple times and keep reordering the word in order to check for each possibility.

Is this the best solution? or there's another approach?

I have an idea of how to make this code but it doesn't seem the best approach in my mind. In case it's not obvious I'm very much a beginner ...

Answer (score 1):

One simple approach would be to store each word in a table like this:

```
Key    | Value
---------------
dgo    | dog
dgo    | god
act    | act
act    | cat
act    | tac
```

The key is the letters of the word ordered alphabetically, while the value is the actual word.

Then, to find the anagrams of `tac` you simply need to order the letters alphabetically, and then perform a simple lookup.

This will get you very fast performance.

A simple optimisation would be to hash the key, for improved lookup speed and reduced data storage, at the expense of having to confirm each word is a genuine anagram (as the hash could result in collisions, although this will be very rare).

Obviously, if you are storing in a database, then storing the key and value in separate tables and joining them together would likely give excellent performance, but for 70k words, it's gonna be fast enough for a toy project however you implement it.

## EDIT

A simple "in-memory" example of this code would be:

```
void Main()
{
    // Setup a database of anagrams. We are using a simple 
    // dictionary here.
    var words = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> 
    {
        ["dgo"] = new List<string> { "dog", "god"},
        ["act"] = new List<string> { "act", "cat", "tac" }
    };

    // Ask the user for a word to search.
    var wordToSearch = Console.ReadLine();

    // Get the lookup key.
    var key = GetKey(wordToSearch);

    // Lookup the anagrams, excluding the word that was input.
    var anagrams = words[key].Where(word => word != wordToSearch);

    // Print out the anagrams.
    foreach(var anagram in anagrams)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(anagram);
    }
}

// Calculates a key for "word". This function must return a value that 
// will be the same for any anagram of "word".
public string GetKey(string word)
{
    return new String(word.OrderBy(c => c).ToArray());
}
```

## EDIT2

To construct the dictionary from a text file:

I am assuming your text file looks like this:

```
cat
dog
tac
act
god
```

Then the following code can read it in:

```
var file = @"C:\temp\words.txt";
var words = new Dictionary<string, IList<string>>(); 

using (var stream = File.OpenRead(file))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    while(!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var word = reader.ReadLine().Trim();
        var key2 = GetKey(word);

        if (!words.ContainsKey(key2))
        {
            words[key2] = new List<string>();
        }

        words[key2].Add(word);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, for now I have only the text file with the 70k words, how can i arrange it in 2 tables? Because there are all kind of words, I can't see a way to do that, unless who makes the file would know to arrange them in some way, so far they are alphabetically. Could you maybe tell me how to do it in my case? I don't see a way to modify this table to look like your example :)

Comment: I think it can be an interesting example, because it can happen to have a file with a lot of data and we need to do different things with it, this is what i'm trying to learn, if i have this file what can i do with this data which i put in the table to search for anagrams

Comment: @sgcata I've added some code showing how to read in a text file into a dictionary. However, your question is starting to go out of scope of the original question - can I suggest you raise new questions if you have any new queries...?

Comment: hi, i appreciate the help to read from a file, but i had found a way before to read, as i wrote, i already made a search in this db that i created. but now i need a way to find the anagrams. so i already have the DB, now when i write "Listen" it needs to search the db and find "Silent" snd any other anagrams that there may exist there. this is what is my question, which way can i use to achieve this? If you cna help me i can give best answer, so far i didn't found online how to do it at least in some way efficiently. Thank you :D

Comment: i mean i can search for every word and realign both words and then see if they are equal but i'm not sure this is a good way. i'll probably start doing this and if i find another way in the meantime i will change it

Comment: @sgcata I feel you haven't understood what I'm suggesting. Basically, you construct a key for every word in your dictionary. The key MUST have the property that every anagram generates the same key. I've suggested taking the letters in alphabetical order, as that is a nice simple approach. 

Once you have your key, then to find every anagram very quickly you simply use the key to lookup all the words with that same key. My example uses a dictionary, but in a database this can also be very quick, as you can use an index, or a primary key/foreign key relationship.